# Labels in italics for x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to label words in italics for x axis?

Code:

```
nr$species <- factor(nr$species,
                     levels=c( "Gaur", "Sambar", "SpottedDeer", "IndianMuntjac", "WildBoar"))
```

Answer (score 8):

Change the looks of text in *ggplot* using *theme*:

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "italic"))
```